# Cells counting problem

Tags: algorithm

There is a 3D grid with cells for which we define its value (0 or 1) as `F(i,j,k)=F(i-1,j,k) XOR F(i,j-1,k) XOR F(i,j,k-1)`, base cases are `F(0,0,0)=1` and `F(x,y,z)=0` for `x < 0 or y < 0 or z < 0` (if at least one parameter is negative).
We want to count amount of cells with `F()=1` in the cube with corners `(0,0,0)` and `(N, M, K)`. Dimensions are about `2^30`.

I'm looking for the fast approach on this problem.

Comment: 2^30? Better start counting then, instead of wasting your time (and anyone else's) here...

Comment: @eljenso, really? You are so smart and extremely fast to find the result for this problem applying only counting? N is <= 10^9 in this case!

Comment: Why, exactly? What we do know, if this is a homework-y type question, is that there must be a formula to work this out, 2^30 in each dimension makes it too big to brute force.

Comment: Looks like "plz do the homework for me" question to me. What have you tried? And what is "^"? Power? XOR?

Comment: It is not a a homework. For 2D this function produces interesting picture of nested rectangles. I am wondering about the formula-based solution for it.

Comment: @Konrad, yes, I've plotted the picture for each slice. But don't see any keys how to address the counting.

Comment: Anyone can see the results here: [link](http://pastie.org/2325056)

Comment: BTW. You may have more luck at math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Hey, that's cool. Wish I knew. :-)

Comment: What you describe is very similar to cellular automata http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_cellular_automaton

Comment: I don't see a way to prove it analytically, but how about this: Take an 8x8 piece from a slice. Notice that in a 16x16 piece there are 3 such 8x8 pieces. Then in a 32x32 piece there are 3 such 16x16 pieces. And so on, repeat ~30 times.